# The relationship between regular distribution and tensor product of distribution?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

For a regular distribution $T_f$, where $f$ is defined on $\mathbb R^n$,
$$
\langle T_f, \varphi\rangle := \int_{\mathbb R^n}  f(x) \varphi(x) dx.
$$
The tensor product of two distributions $S$ and $T$ is definded by
$$
\langle T \otimes S, \varphi \rangle := \langle T, \langle S, \varphi_\cdot \rangle \rangle,
$$
where
$$
\varphi_\cdot(y) = \varphi(\cdot, y).
$$
If $T_f$ and $T_g$ are two regular distributions, where $f$ is defined on $\mathbb R^n$ and $g$ on $\mathbb R^m$, then
$$
\langle T_f \otimes T_g, \varphi \rangle = \int_{\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^m} f(x) g(y) \varphi(x, y) dx dy,
$$
so that the tensor product of distribution is a special case of a regular distribution, ie. $T_f \otimes T_g = T_h$, where $h(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. By the definition of the tensor product of distributions,

$$
\langle T_f \otimes T_g, \varphi \rangle = \langle T_f, x \mapsto \int_{\mathbb R^m} g(y) \varphi(x, y) dy \rangle = \int_{\mathbb R^m} f(x) \int_{\mathbb R^m} g(y) \varphi(x, y) dy dx,
$$
which by Fubini's theorem equals the integral you describe in your question.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @AiliyEvan: If you want to display your appreciation for an answer, you may upvote it or accept it as correct by clicking the button below the up- and downvote buttons, or, preferably, both.